# Dynamically reference different sheets in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to reference different sheets in a macro without explicitly referencing them so as to make the macro compatible with any range of sheets. I have happily been using (ActiveSheet.Index +/- 1) for switching between sheets, but when it comes to entering formulae, I can't find anything to help me so far.

The route I have gone down thus far is using a macro I found at: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/sheetref.htm

which references the name of the next sheet when entered in a cell. e.g. =NextSheetName() returns 'Sheet 2'.

I combine that result with an ! mark and define it as nexxxtsheet.

So when I enter the Formula

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & nexxxtsheet & " "A1"
```

I expect the cell to have the formula: ='Name of next sheet'!A1

However it returns ='Name of next sheet'!'A1'

The difference being the quotes around A1 - rendering the formula useless. I am rather new to VBA and have no idea why this happens, and I am entirely certain that the method I am using to switch sheets without a direct reference is, for lack of a better term, rather crackhouse-style. I am very open to suggestions of how I should better switch between sheets, or corrections to render my formula useful.

Thanks all!

Comment: Define `Dim nexxxtsheet As String` , the set it  `nexxxtsheet = "Sheet2"` (for instance), and the use the `Formula` (not `FormulaR1C1`) like : `ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & nexxxtsheet & "!" & "A1"` . Keep in mind, it is better to avoid using `ActiveCell`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help - as I am new I was wondering if you could explain what the difference between formula and Formula R1C1 was?

Comment: @LukasLjungstrom R1C1 is another way of referencing cells (by their **R**ow and **C**olumn number). For example R2C3 is the cell usually known as C2. `.FormulaR1C1` is used to set the formula with these references (excel will convert them afterwards) so it doesn't understand A1 as a cell reference. If you search for R1C1 reference style you will find lots of information.

Answer (score 1):

with "formula" , not "formulaR1C1", it works for me. Except if cell format is text, in which case you need to change it first